# dev_queue_xmit results in kernel panic

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I am writing a part of kernel module which transfers skbuff from one interface out to another interface. Ex all packet coming on eth0, gets forwarded out to on eth1. The problem even the first packet I intend to transmit is resulting in kernel crash in dev_queue_xmit(). Can anyone help me understand whats going wrong here ?. Kernel Panic occurs in

<2>kernel BUG at net/core/skbuff.c:927!

code sample function that I am using to transmit packet is as below. Please let me know.

```
enter code here

   int txPktOnOtherIf(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *tdev)
   {
    int reservedSpace=max((int)LL_RESERVED_SPACE(tdev),(int)sizeof(struct ethhdr));
    int buffLen = reservedSpace - sizeof(struct ethhdr) + skb->len + skb->dev->needed_tailroom;
    struct sk_buff* nskb = NULL;
    int err = 0;

    printk("ReservedSpace is %d and buffer len is %d",reservedSpace,buffLen);
    nskb = alloc_skb(buffLen, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!nskb) {
             printk("Couldn't allocate SKB\n");
            return -1;
    }
    skb_reserve(nskb, reservedSpace);
    skb_reset_network_header(nskb);
    skb_put(nskb, skb->len - sizeof(struct ethhdr));
    skb_push(nskb, sizeof(struct ethhdr));
    skb_reset_mac_header(nskb);
    skb_reset_mac_len(nskb);
    err = skb_store_bits(nskb, 0, skb->data, skb->len);
    if (err) {
            kfree_skb(nskb);
            printk("Error %d storing to SKB\n", err);
            return -1;
    }
    nskb->dev = tdev;
    nskb->protocol = skb->protocol;
    skb_get(nskb);
    err = dev_queue_xmit(nskb);
    err = net_xmit_eval(err);
    if (err) {
            kfree_skb(nskb);
            printk("Error %d sending frame\n", err);
            return -1;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Which distro and which kernel are you using? On which architecture? Also, could you post the whole call stack of the kernel panic?